# ¿Por qué se pierden milisegundos al usar funciones de espera?

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de realizar un programa que haga peticiones cada minuto exacto, encontré varias funciones en el camino, pero muchas de ellas pierden algunos milisegundos y en determinado tiempo sumando esas perdidas será 1 segundo o más, eso me va a generar problemas y desfases importantes, a lo que me refiero es lo siguiente:

> tiempo_1.py

```
import time

contador = 0
while contador < 10:
    print datetime.now()
    contador += 1
    time.sleep(30)
```

Resultados:

```
2017-01-26 11:48:48.813558
2017-01-26 11:49:18.833623
2017-01-26 11:49:48.836416
2017-01-26 11:50:18.860363
2017-01-26 11:50:48.868115
2017-01-26 11:51:18.897203
2017-01-26 11:51:48.926559
2017-01-26 11:52:18.953411
2017-01-26 11:52:48.982873
2017-01-26 11:53:18.988292
```

Empieza en .81 y termina en .98, en 10 repeticiones perdí 0.17 segundos

> tiempo_2.py

```
from datetime import datetime
import schedule
import time

def tiempo():
    print datetime.now()

schedule.every(30).seconds.do(tiempo)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Resultados:

```
2017-01-26 11:54:23.268964
2017-01-26 11:54:53.302266
2017-01-26 11:55:23.335505
2017-01-26 11:55:53.367644
2017-01-26 11:56:23.397164
2017-01-26 11:56:53.430264
2017-01-26 11:57:23.462877
2017-01-26 11:57:53.494474
2017-01-26 11:58:23.526921
2017-01-26 11:58:53.559479
```

En este caso perdí 0.29 segundos desde la primera hasta la décima vez.

Al principio pensé que era por usar los prints, los eliminé y use inserciones en listas, seguía perdiendo el mismo tiempo, quite las listas y solo medí el tiempo y hacía debug con logging, perdía el mismo tiempo ¿A que se debe? ¿Cómo puedo evitarlo? ¿Cómo hago que mi programa se ejecute n veces a las 11:58:53.0000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues tengo malas noticias para ti, no vas a lograr que cada segundo exacto se realice una petición, ya que como sabes el computador tiene un MicroProcesador, el cual se encarga de ejecutar todas las instrucciones que tu programa le envíe, pero además de eso se encarga de procesar las instrucciones de todos los demás procesos que se encuentren activos en ese momento (SO, tu programa, antivirus, la música que corres).

El procesador tiene una cantidad limitada de instrucciones que puede procesar por segundo y solo puede ejecutar una instrucción a la vez (con los procesadores de varios núcleos esto cambia, pues cada núcleo ejecuta una instrucción en un tiempo X). Así que aunque te parezca increíble, incluso cuando escuchas una canción en tu computadora, hay momentos en los cuales el CPU no está mandándole a los parlantes la instrucción de que reproduzca un sonido.

Ahora bien, entonces como es que la música se escucha "Seguido" y puedo ejecutar mi programada y parece "Seguido" mientras se ejecutan también todos los procesos de SO. Pues los procesadores tienen una [frecuencia de reloj](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frecuencia_de_reloj), que junto con las cantidades de núcleos y la tecnología con la cual se hayan construido te dará la cantidad de instrucciones que puede ejecutar en un segundo tu procesador ([se mide en millones](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millones_de_instrucciones_por_segundo))

Entonces ¿Por qué pierdes milisegundos?, para responder a esto, además de lo antes dicho debes de saber que:

- Los procesos tienen un estado.
- Los procesos se manejan por cola, pero aún así cada proceso tiene una prioridad que puede cambiar esa cola.

Los estados son los siguientes:

1. Elemento de lista
2. Ejecución: El proceso está en ejecución se encuentra procesándose
3. Listo: El proceso está listo para ser procesado, está en espera para entrar a ejecución
4. En espera: El proceso no puede ejecutarse hasta que se produzca cierto evento (en este estado pones a tu proceso cuando haces un `time.sleep(1)`)
5. Nuevo: El proceso se creó y está en espera de ser admitido por el SO.
6. Terminado: El proceso acabó y fue excluido de la cola de procesos.

Con respecto a la prioridad, un proceso con alta prioridad entrará antes que uno con baja o media (cada CPU tiene sus algoritmos para calcular las prioridades y determinar cuando entra un proceso y cuando no). Con respecto a esto debes de tener en cuenta que los SO generalmente tienen prioridades altas en sus procesos.

Así entonces a la hora de hacer el time.sleep pones a tu proceso en modo de espera por un n tiempo, al pasar este lapso no significa que tu proceso entrará en ese instante, pues el se encuentra en una cola.

Finalmente recuerda que cada instrucción de tu programa tarda un tiempo (incluyendo los ciclos, los print...) y además recuerda que una función que llames como datetime.now() también tiene instrucciones adentro que también tardan un tiempo en ejecutarse, en el cual también pasa un tiempo, además del que ya se estás dando en el `time.sleep`.

Así que no culpes a las funciones de espera, culpa a también las instrucciones y funciones que escribes o que llamas.

Nota: cualquier instrucción que mandan algo a cualquier dispositivo periférico, como el imprimir algo en pantalla tardan más tiempo que otras instrucciones que solo tienen que realizar operaciones aritméticas y lógicas

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación, no lo tenía en cuenta, no soy informático y no sabía eso. Al principio mencionas que no podré hacer que se ejecute en un tiempo exacto, pero por ejemplo ¿se podría dentro de un intervalo? por ejemplo de 11:58:53.0000 a 11:58:53.9999 sin que en algún momento pase a 11:58:54.0000

Comment: Tendrías que poner un tiempo de menos de un segundo, además como te digo, tienes que tomar en cuenta que cada instrucción que ejecutes también tarda un tiempo

Answer (score 2):

A ver:

1. Teoricamente no creo que puedas garantizar eso con ningun programa al menos que utilices un [Sistema Operativo de Tiempo Real](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_operativo_de_tiempo_real)
2. Una búsqueda de "Python+Real Time" no arrojó resultados muy esperanzadores.

La razón porque no puedes garantizar que las cosas van a pasar al segundo exacto es que aunque no lo creas al sistema operativo le deja de importar un poco tu aplicación cada vez que llamas a `sleep`, o estas esperando por E/S, o el intérprete de `Python` chequea si [puede cambiar el contexto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock) y ejecutar el código nativo necesario para sacar los caracteres por la terminal.

Si miras este artículo sobre [el comando time](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_(Unix)), quizás te aclare un poco más

Comment: Gracias al link del comando time ahora lo entiendo, creo que podría mejorar un poco recurriendo a Cython, gracias.